# Regex for removing characters from numbers, but not all characters

Tags: regex

I have a column in OpenRefine, I want to manipulate:

There are Strings (example: FL), Strings containing numbers (123F423), and numbers

I want to get rid of all letters (A-Z) that "pollute" the numbers (like the 123F423), but i do not want to change anything on the "clean" strings and numbers.

Example:

FL       -> FL

123F324  -> 123324

432531   -> 432531

AB       -> AB

342J34   -> 34234

Comment: do you mean to replace `123FL423`  to `123F423` ?

Comment: Not really sure how you could understand it like this. From 123F423 I want to go to 123423

Comment: mmm, explain more, show us input output example to understand more

Comment: just edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search and remove:

```
(?<=\d)[A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z]+(?=\d)
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sb1bqW/1)

The regex means one or more letter that are not preceded by a number or that are not followed by a number. It uses [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

EDIT: If lookaround is not supported, you can simply search for

```
(\d)[A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z]+(\d)
```

and replace with `$1$2` (see [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Sb1bqW/2))

Comment: That's a VERY interesting solution via substitution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want in a single operation as regex is designed to provide a specific match rather than the absence of a match and it will not concatenate multiple results for you.

For example, you can either repeatedly regex for `[A-Z]+` and remove the offending matches or search once for all numbers `[0-9]+` in a single regex and concatenate all resulting matches.

The second option would be faster as it only evaluates the expression once.

**EDIT**

@horcrux has a much better answer.